# Checkbox.isChecked() returns null

Tags: java, android, class, adapter

I created a CategoryChild class with a checkbox and a string for the checkbox text. Now I want to access to the Checkbox state in my adapter, but it returns null, what could be the problem?

**Adapter**

```
 private ArrayList<CategoryName> categoryTopic = new ArrayList<>();
 private ArrayList<CategoryName> allValues = new ArrayList<>();
 private ArrayList<CategoryName> checkedValues = new ArrayList<>();
 private ArrayList<CategoryName> uncheckedValues = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    CategoryName parentItem = categoryTopic.get(position);
    holder.categoryName.setText(parentItem.categoryName);

    setCatItemRecycler(holder.childRecView, categoryTopic.get(position).getChildViewList(), parentItem.getCategoryName());
}

private void setCatItemRecycler(RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<CategoryChild> categoryChildrenList, String categoryName) {

    childAdapter = new SchrankChildAdapter(context, categoryChildrenList, categoryName);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(childAdapter);
}

private Filter spinnerFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        ArrayList<CategoryName> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<CategoryChild> filteredSubList = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean containsSubItems = false;

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0 || constraint.equals("all")) {

            filteredList.addAll(allValues);

        }  else if(constraint.equals("checked")) {

            ArrayList<CategoryChild> checkedChildList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(CategoryName parent: categoryTopic) {

                for(CategoryChild child: parent.getChildViewList()) {

                    System.out.println(child.getCategoryAttribute() + " has the Checkbox State: " + child.getCheckBoxState());
                    /*if(child.getCheckBoxState()) {
                        checkedChildList.add(new CategoryChild(child.getCategoryAttribute()));
                    }*/
                    checkedValues.add(new CategoryName(parent.categoryName, checkedChildList));
                    checkedChildList.clear();
                }
            }
           // filteredList.addAll(checkedValues);

        } else if(constraint.equals("unchecked")) {

            filteredList.addAll(uncheckedValues);

        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if(filteredList != null) {
            results.values = filteredList;
        }
        else {
            results.values = allValues;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        /*categoryTopic.clear();
        categoryTopic.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
*/
    }
};

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView categoryName;
    RelativeLayout childView;
    RecyclerView childRecView;
    Button btFolderPlus, btFolderMinus;
    Spinner dropDownMenu;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        childView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.childView);
        childRecView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.childRecView);
        btFolderPlus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btFolderPlus);
        btFolderMinus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btFolderMinus);
        dropDownMenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dropDown);
    }
}
```

**CategoryChild Class**

```
public class CategoryChild {

private CheckBox checkBox;
private String checkBoxText;

public CategoryChild(String categoryAttribute) {
    this.checkBoxText = categoryAttribute;
}

public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
    return checkBox;
}

public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
    this.checkBox = checkBox;
}

public String getCategoryAttribute() {
    return checkBoxText;
}

public void setCategoryAttribute(String categoryAttribute) {
    this.checkBox.setText(categoryAttribute);
}

public boolean getCheckBoxState()
{
    return checkBox.isChecked();
}

public void setCheckBoxState(boolean isChecked) {
    checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
}
}
```

**So this line of code from my adapter causes an error:**

> System.out.println(child.getCategoryAttribute() + " has the Checkbox State: " + child.getCheckBoxState());

**The exception:**

```
Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
    at com.atromic.cookedia.CategoryChild.getCheckBoxState(CategoryChild.java:32)
    at com.atromic.cookedia.SchrankAdapter$2.performFiltering(SchrankAdapter.java:184)
    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:236)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I tested the same line without the getCheckBoxState() and just printing the name of that checkbox and it works. So there must be a value in the arraylist, but I'm not able to get the checkbox state, only the name of it.

**UPDATE:**
I'll add my childAdapter which basically handles the checkboxes.

**ChildAdapter**

```
public SchrankChildAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryChild> childItemArrayList, String categoryName) {
    this.context = context;
    this.childItemArrayList = childItemArrayList;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    uncheckedSubList.addAll(childItemArrayList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_category_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    CategoryChild childItem = childItemArrayList.get(position);

    holder.checkBox.setText(childItem.getCategoryAttribute());
    childItem.setCheckBox(holder.checkBox);

    childItem.getCheckBox().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(childItem.getCheckBoxState()) {
                System.out.println("Checkbox: " + childItem.getCategoryAttribute() + " is " + childItem.getCheckBoxState());
                childItem.getCheckBox().setChecked(true);
                checkedSubList.add(new CategoryChild(childItem.getCategoryAttribute()));
                deleteChidList(uncheckedSubList, childItem.getCategoryAttribute());
                containsChecked = true;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(!childItem.getCheckBoxState()) {
                System.out.println("Checkbox: " + childItem.getCategoryAttribute() + " is " + childItem.getCheckBoxState());
                childItem.getCheckBox().setChecked(false);
                uncheckedSubList.add(new CategoryChild(childItem.getCategoryAttribute()));
                deleteChidList(checkedSubList, childItem.getCategoryAttribute());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void deleteChidList(ArrayList<CategoryChild> list, String childName){

    if(list.size() > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            if(childName.equals(list.get(i).getCategoryAttribute()))
                list.remove(i);

        }
    }
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CheckBox checkBox;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Checkbox.isChecked()` doesn't return null. `checkbox` is null

Comment: But why and how can I fix that?

Comment: set the checkbox via `setCheckBox`

Comment: My checkbox handler happens in another adapter, the "SchrankChildAdapter". I will edit my post to let you see what handles my checkboxes.